# elasticsearch's source code

Tags: maven, elasticsearch

I got failed to build elasticsearch by maven(i wrote pom)

I found that there lack some source files, i.e. (org.elasticsearch.common.base.*)

I build from the master branch.

My question is, are there any extra source files?

Comment: The [build page](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/appendix/building-from-source.html) says: "it will take some time to download all the dependencies elasticsearch has." Did you run their build tool? Which dependencies have you installed yourself?

Answer (score 3):

I've successfully manged to build elasticsearch via maven:
https://github.com/karussell/elasticsearch/blob/auth/modules/elasticsearch/pom.xml

The trick is to let gradle generate the jarjar things and install the deps by hand:
https://github.com/karussell/elasticsearch/blob/auth/modules/jarjar/install.sh

Comment: here is the pull request: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/1456

Comment: btw: elasticsearch now uses maven instead of gradle